# select by max id into max date

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, max

I have a query that look like this:

```
with t as ( 
             ****** complex query from several joining tables  ***** 
          )
select * from t;
```

the query return a list of entities by their id.
like (it doesn't really matter) :

> 12001 
>   12004 
>   15003

beside this, I also have table that contain 3 columns:

sequence
entity (from above)
value_date (format: dd/mm/yyyy)
the value date it's not the same for all entity.

For example, the table look like that:

```
seq           entity        value_date 
----------    ----------    ----------  
1580          12001         31/05/2016 
1579          12001         30/06/2016 
1578          15003         30/06/2016 
1577          12001         30/06/2016 
1576          15003         30/06/2016 
1575          15003         30/06/2016 
1574          12004         30/06/2016
1573          15003         31/05/2016 
1572          12004         31/05/2016 
1571          67677         30/04/2016
```

I need to run for each entity (from the query, because the table hold also irrelevant entities for me), and select the max sequence with the max value_date for the entities. (in other words, find for each entity the max value_date, and inside that, the max seq).

The result needs to be, list with 3 columns: seq, entity, value_date.
How can I do it?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off with a view and joining to this view, especially if you need this logic (select highest date, highest seq for each entity) more than once.

`create view (...viewname...)`  - the SELECT part as below:

```
select seq, entity, value_date 
from   (
          select seq, entity, value_date, 
                 row_number() over 
                            (partition by entity order by value_date desc, seq desc) as rn
          from   t2
       )
where  rn = 1;
```

Then:

```
with t as ( ... )
select t.*, v.seq, v.value_date
from   t inner join viewname v
         on t.entity = v.entity
```

From re-reading your post, it seems all you really needed was the `select` portion of the view definition - use it any way you need.

I wasn't sure when you said value_date is in format dd/mm/yyyy - that seems to imply it is in VARCHAR2 or other similar string format, not an actual date. In that case your best option is to fix your data structure and make it date data type. Otherwise you will need to use `to_date(value_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` instead of simply `value_date`.

Comment: maybe... i will consider it.

Comment: the value_date is in date format. (value_date is just the name of column)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  Here is a method that doesn't require aggregation:

```
with t as ( 
             ****** complex query from several joining tables  ***** 
      )
select t.*,
       (select max(t2.seq) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc)
        from t2
        where t2.entity = t.entity
       ) as max_seq
from t;
```

If you need the date as well, you can get that more easily:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(t2.seq) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.date desc)
        from t2
        where t2.entity = t.entity
       ) as max_seq,
       (select max(t2.date)
        from t2
        where t2.entity = t.entity
       ) as max_date
from t;
```